# Reading and writing CAN messages through ELM327

Tags: uart, raspberry-pi, can, obd

I have an [OBD-II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics#OBD-II) cable, and an UART-to-OBD-II board which has the [ELM327](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELM327) IC in it. I want to communicate with my [ECU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_control_unit) by sending-receiving CAN messages. Is it possible to communicate through ELM 327?

I've been able to diagnose the ECU to fetch basic information through the UART board (ELM327) using [HyperTerminal](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/app_terminal.mspx) and [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can!

ELM 327 supports AT Commands (See this [PDF](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Widgets/ELM327_AT_Commands.pdf) ).
You can set filters for required CAN IDs or J1939 PGNs and it will return you corrosponding CAN Data over UART.

Check list of commands. They are self-explanatory.

P.S. ELM 327 has special command for DM1. DM1 is a J1939 PGN which has information about all active faults. Do check that!

Comment: Thanks.  I also want to know whether you have idea about Diagnostic Trouble Codes in a car? I want to fetch the DTCs(if available)and show them in terminal.

Comment: @user3098378 See the info in my answer to your other question that got migrated: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8233/accessing-diagnostic-trouble-codes-dtcs-in-car/8273#8273

Comment: Thanks for the answer @swanand ! I know this is an old thread, but I'm trying to transmit raw CAN frames on the ELM327 for a custom protocol (okay actually just XCP plus some J1939 messages) and can't find an AT command to accomplish this. Any thoughts?

Comment: @darkpbj You can set CAN address using ATSH (Set Header) and after that, send your custom PID, It will be formed in the message with preset header and transmitted on the bus.